# Automatic updates for android App

Tags: android

Need to know if Android will automatically ask for app updates or do we need to integrate it manually within the code ? 
Also, if automatic updates are there, can users prevent updates from being installed ?

Comment: Bad question and set a incorrect answer to right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Android will automatically ask for updates, and you do not need to integrate it manually. Also, yes, users can prevent updates from being installed.

Comment: android app,not android os

Comment: Yes, I am asking about an app i am developing. Got two conflicting answers !!

Comment: @Bhavna Look at my comment on his answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you install the app using Google Play Store the updates will be handled by Google Play Store itself. So it will get updated automatically. You don't need to write any extra code for it.

If the user has enabled Automatically install app updates then the update will be automatic if no extra permissions are required.

But its better to show a notification that the app has an update in your app. You can check for updates in splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need update(download) new version from your server.then replace the old apk. so yes ,you shoud write code yourself.

Comment: Everything is done via the App Manager. Android will auto update your push a new version of the APK.

Comment: Not corret, android is not ios,so many custom os ,and you can't  guarantee all worked in app manager.

Comment: If the Android OS automatically does the updating, there is no reason to implement something in the code. I dont get what you are saying.

Comment: Be remember! android is open source platform,you can't guarantee app update by one market(like.google play).so you should do it by yourself sometimes